# Kill all running threads

Tags: mysql, sql

I can do `show full processlist` to get all the data of the running threads. However, is there a way to just get the thread_id so I can do a concat to generate a "kill" statement? Currently, I have to copy and paste everything into a text editor to append the "kill" command for each thread id. For example, to do something like:

```
select concat('call mysql.rds_kill(', id, ');') from (
    show full processlist
);
```

Then I could copy paste what it generates to kill all the running threads.

Comment: You also need to make sure that you don't kill the query killing the other queries. BTW why do you want to kill all threads without shutting down the DBMS?

Comment: @symcbean this is something I do every so often when I need to do an alter table command and I get transaction/metadata locks and I can see what other threads are running (and nothing too important is running).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to kill all running `mysql` processes, try this:

```
for process in `ps -ef|grep mysql |awk -F" " '{print $2}'`
do
kill -9 $process
done
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Oh.. I guess I gave you a solution in Shell script. I'll remove it if you don't need it. Just confirm.